# React: What should I use instead of an array index in the "key" prop?

Tags: reactjs

I understand **why** you shouldn't use an array index in the `key` prop. There are plenty of existing SO answers and blog posts explaining how this can cause bugs.

But I can't find much advice on **what to do instead**. The standard advice is just 'Use an ID that uniquely identifies the item' — but what about when there is no such unique ID available?

Say you've been tasked with writing a component, and the component will be passed an array of items (without anything that can be used as a unique ID), and you need to map over this array to render a list of DOM nodes. What should you do in this case?

Options:

- Just use the array index as `key` anyway, and suppress your linter's warning about it.
- Don't set a `key` prop at all. (But then React will give you a warning at runtime - unless there's a way to opt out of this warning?)
- Something else?

Comment: "without anything that can be used as a unique ID" that's pretty rare edge case. Usually you do have something that identifies item in a list somehow. Anyway you can assign some synthetic id to each item using some flavour of a `guid`.

Comment: Any JS iterator gives you item and index, use that index as a unique key. This is very obvious and simple

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi no, you should not use an array index as a `key` in React, and there are plenty of discussions about why. https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: The discussion you have mentioned is invalid, cause having something else appearing in the middle that ruins the sequence of the index, shows bad architecture :) that should not happen + medium.com is not a good programing source

Comment: if you have nested maps , for the first map you can have `key={index1}` for nested ones `key=${index1}-${index2}` and so on

Comment: in the most complicated projects, I have done (tables with 4 level of nested mapping), I have never faced such a problem. otherwise the several years of React development, there should have been hundreds of issues in the repository of React regarding this

Comment: That Medium post is just the first of many discussions that came up on Google. React’s official docs also explicitly warn against using an array index as key, and there are plenty of answers on SO giving clear examples of major bugs that can result from it. Many popular shared linting configs also ban it. You can of course disagree and make an argument against it, but you can’t just dismiss the prevailing and official view out of hand.

Comment: Upvoted. This is a good question, and I would also like an equally good answer from somebody in the community.

Comment: @callum holy shit, sorry about that weirdo.